# deleting my page tab using graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to delete an page tab app that i have installed on a page using the graphAPI.

I think i am close.
here is where i am ( will try to remove fluff)

i have my pageID $pageID

```
$page_info = $facebook->api("/".$pageID."?fields=access_token");
if( !empty($page_info['access_token']) ) {
            $args = array(
                'access_token'  => $page_info['access_token']
            );
            $pageAccessToken = $page_info['access_token'];
}
$result = $facebook->api('/'.$pageID.'/tabs/'.FB_APP_ID,
                         'delete', 
                          array('access_token' => $pageAccessToken));
```

but i get the error"
    Tab is not installed or not removable: Exception-->[(#100) Tab is not installed or not removable:

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found my problem

```
'/'.$pageID.'/tabs/'.FB_APP_ID
```

should have been

```
'/'.$pageID.'/tabs/app_'.FB_APP_ID
```

I was mising the app_ after /tabs/